# Inspecting and live-modifying a call argument from a decorator

Tags: python, python-2.7

My use case is the following:

```
@AddOne("b")
def func(a, b, c, *args, **kwargs):
    print a, b, c
```

expected behaviour:

```
>>> func(1, 2, 3)
1 3 3
>>> func(a=1, c=3, b=2)
1 3 3
```

I suspect that I must code the decorator while using `inspect` module with something like `getcallargs` or `getargspec`, but I am unable to perform it programatically. Am I missing something?

Edit: My try is something along the following:

```
class AddOne(object):
    def __init__(self, param_name):
        self.param_name = param_name

    def __call__(self, func):
        @wraps(func)
        def decorated(*args, **kwargs):
            new_args = list(args)
            new_kwargs = kwargs

            v = extract_parameter_somehow(
                func, new_args, kwargs, 
                self.param_name) + 1

            kwargs[self.param_name] = v
            return func(*new_args, **kwargs)
        return decorated
```

Comment: What does your decorator look like?

Comment: @idjaw Yeah you are right, I was just editing the post. I realized that didn't adapt my work in progress source code to the question :-/ I was multitasking too much...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The module `inspect` contains all you need to meet your requirements:

- `getargspec` gives you the exact definition to know the parameters and their order
- `getcallargs` processes the actual parameters and gives their values

Code could be:

```
 class AddOne(object):
    def __init__(self, param_name):
        self.param_name = param_name

    def __call__(self, func):
        self.argspec = inspect.getargspec(func)
        @wraps(func)
        def decorated(*args, **kwargs):
            callargs = inspect.getcallargs(func, *args, **kwargs)
            if callargs.has_key(self.param_name):
        callargs[self.param_name] += 1
        elif callargs[self.argspec.keywords].has_key(self.param_name):
        callargs[self.argspec.keywords][self.param_name] += 1
            new_args = [ callargs[i] for i in self.argspec.args
             ] + list(callargs[self.argspec.varargs])
            new_kwargs = callargs[self.argspec.keywords]
            return func(*new_args, **kwargs)
        return decorated
```

That means:

- use getcallargs to process default values and positional parameters given as keyed parameters
- search param_name in positional parameter - if found increase corresponding value
- if not found in positional parameters, search it in keyword arguments - if found increase corresponding values

Then, the list of positional arguments and the hash for keyword ones are built from the `getcallargs` returned value, to allow the possibilities of extra varargs or other keyword parameters.

Comment: thanks! I had found the `getcallargs` thing, but I messed up because didn't understand the `varargs` and `keywords`, which are the key to the problem.

Answer (score 0):

An option (maybe a bit hackish?) is to use `getargspec` and then performing destructive lookups to `args` and `kwargs`

```
# ...
    def __call__(self, func):
        arg_names = getargspec(func).args
        self.param_index = arg_names.index(self.param_name)

        @wraps(func)
        def decorated(*args, **kwargs):
            new_args = list(args)
            new_kwargs = kwargs

            try:
                v = new_args.pop(self.param_index)
            except IndexError:
                v = new_kwargs.pop(self.param_name) 
            new_kwargs[self.param_name] = v + 1
            return func(*new_args, **new_kwargs)
        return decorated
```